# Is the bending issue a problem in iPhone 6 or just iPhone 6+?

Tags: iphone

Obviously, the bending issue is a widely known problem with the newest iPhones. Is this a problem with just the iPhone 6+ or also the iPhone 6?

Comment: Can you improve your question?  I can't think of anything that can't be bent, and yes there's a lot of publicity around the new iPhones bending in people's pockets.  Please be more specific about exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

> If you apply enough force to an inch-thick solid steel rod, it will
>   bend.
>
> Same goes for the quarter-inch-thick iPhone 6 and 6 Plus (which, I
>   should note, have far less than a quarter of an inch of aluminum in
>   any one spot).
>
> Aluminum is actually a fairly soft metal, ranking at 2.5-to-3 on the
>   Mohs scale of hardness.
>
> That is to say, it's about as tough as a U.S. penny (which is actually
>   97.5% zinc and just plated in copper).

<sup>Source: http://www.imore.com/yes-aluminum-iphone-6-and-6-plus-can-be-bent-if-too-much-pressure-applied</sup>

I would not recommend to stick it in the back pocket of a very tight jeans, and then repeatedly sit on it.

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue for any phone size depending on the amount of force you apply. Larger phones require less force to bend them—a larger magnitude of force for a smaller phone will still bend it. Whether a device bends in your pocket depends on the force you are applying.